# original mean from centered array

Tags: r, centering

Given the mean-centered array `a <- c(-2.25,0.75,-1.25,2.75,-0.25,1.75,-0.25,-1.25)` is it possible to retrieve the mean of the original array used to center it without knowing the values of the original array?

Comment: No.  This has been asked and answered here in the context of reconstructing a time series from its first differences.  You can answer it yourself by adding (literally) any two different numbers to your array and observing you get two different arrays yielding the same mean-centered array.

Comment: Thank you @whuber, yes, now I understand.